# Performing a fixed point Iteration upon $f(x)$

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

Let us say we have the function $f(x) = (e^x - 1)^2$. I want to perform a fixed-point iteration upon this function, such that $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$. How can I transform this particular function into a fixed point iteration that converges at the root of $f(x)$? How can this idea be extended to general functions? I am slightly confused at the understanding behind knowing how to transform a given function to a fixed-point iteration method.

EDIT: After trying $g(x) = f(x) + x$, the iterations diverge.

Comment: Try to generalize the answer to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419264/fixed-point-for-finding-a-root

Comment: Could you maybe format an answer? I don't know if I'm being silly but I can't seem to make it work for this case

Comment: Given a function $f(x)$, then a point $x_0$ is a root of $f$ if and only if it is a fixed point of $g(x)=f(x)+x$

Comment: What do you mean by the $-$ after the $x$?

Comment: @Nipster the $-$ after the $x$ is added to the all comments by Math.SE, that's not part of what Alessandro typed.

Comment: @Alessandro So in this case, $g(x) = (e^x -1)^2 + x$ diverges when using a starting point of $x_0 = 0.5, 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a fixed-point iteration will converge if the map you're iterating is  locally a contraction around the fixed-point. Denoting the fixed-point by $z$, an easy way to check if the fixed-point iteration of a continuously differentiable function will converge is to check if $|f'(z)| < 1$. If $|f'(z)| > 1$ you have an instable fixed-point, which means that no matter how close to $z$ you start your iteration, you can not expect the iteration to converge. The intuition behind this is the following first-order linearization:

$$x_{n+1}-x_{n} = f(x_n) - f(x_{n-1}) \approx f'(x_n)(x_n - x_{n-1}) $$
So if $x_n$ is close enough to $z$ such that $f'(x_n) < 1$, you will have that $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| < |x_{n}-x_{n-1}|$, while in the case where $f'(x_0) > 1$ you're gonna have $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| > |x_{n}-x_{n-1}|$ which means that you cannot expect your sequence to converge (although it still might).

EDIT: Corrected this paragraph thanks to @PierreCarre.
So what happens in our example? We have $g(x) = f(x) + x = (e^{x}-1)^2 + x$ whose only fixed-point is $z = 0$,and $g'(x) = 2e^{x} +1 > 1$. We therefore cannot expect the fixed-point iteration to converge. Indeed, for any $x_0 \geq 0$ we have $g(x_n) > x_n$, such that in the iteration we get $x_{n+1} > x_{n}$, and therefore the iteration  will diverge to $+\infty$.
A more well-behaved function whose fixed-points are the roots of $f$ is given by $g(x) = x - (e^{x}-1)^2$.

If you want to practice this kind of reasoning, try finding the fixed-points of $f(x) = x^2$ via fixed-point iteration. Find the derivative of the function and try to predict for which starting values the iterations should converge to which fixed-point, and for which starting values the iteration will diverge, and then try and see if your predictions are correct.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I noticed that for our example, if you were to however try the function $g(x) = x/2 - (e^x - 1)^2$, and an ititial guess $x_0 = 1$, this would converge. Is this still a fixed point iteration?

Comment: It would be of course, but it would slightly complicate the logic of what the fixed points mean. Why not look at $g(x) = x - (e^x -1)^2$? This should still converge, and in this form it is clear that fixed points are roots, because we are now looking at $g(x) = x - f(x)$, so if $g(x) = x$ that means $x = x - f(x)$ which is equvialent to $f(x) =0$.

Comment: @user159517 (+1) But: 1. Denoting the fixed point as $x_0$ is very unfortunate...  2. The fixed point iteration can converge even if $|g'(x_0)|>1$.

Comment: @PierreCarre can you give an example?

Comment: Sure: $g(x) = 1-2x^2, \quad x_0=1$. You have that $z=-1$ is a fixed point, $g'(-1)=4$, but the sequence $x_{n+1}=g(x_n), x_0 =1$ converges to -1.

Comment: Local contractivity is a sufficient condition for convergence, but is not necessary.

Comment: @PierreCarre You are of course perfectly right, thanks for the illuminating example. My mistake was that I negated "x is a stable fixed-point" incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the equation $f(x)=0$ in the form $g(x)=x$ in countless ways. If the equations are equivalent, the roots of $f$ will be the fixed points of $g$. The fixed point method is used to obtain the fixed point(s) of $g$ and takes the form $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$, for some initial approximation $x_0$.

This recursive sequence may or may not converge, and this totally depends on your choice of $g$ (not all are good) and initial approximation. The fixed point theorem establishes sufficient conditions for the convergence of the sequence $(x_n)$: If $g$ is contractive and invariant in some closed non-empty interval $\Omega$, the fixed point iterations will converge regardless of the choice of $x_0 \in\Omega$. The answer by @user159517 focuses on the contractivity condition, and this is ok because you can show that if $g$ is contractive in some neighbourhood $V_{\varepsilon}(z)$ of the fixed point, it satisfies the fixed point theorem conditions in some $V_{\delta}(z)$, $\delta \leq \varepsilon$.

So, if at first you don't succeed... Try to understand why some particular choice of $g$ does not work (for instance plotting its derivative near the fixed point), and rewrite the equation in a different way (other $g$)